# How made dataTable in rowExpansion section in another dataTable with common model

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have complex dataTable witch paganation, dynamic columns, lazyloading, sotring , filtering, multi selection. Now I have to use this table and model in another context. All rows in table now must have "subtable" with the same colums, multiselection woring in outer table context without pagination, sorting, fitering. I schould use dataTable(row Expansion(inner dataTable))?

Answer (score 1):

The actual question is not clear. And I must warn you about heavy table structures in primefaces, they tend to not function as intended. It's generally a good approach to simplify the structure (on JSF/PF elements level).

For example, instead of using tables inside tables you could use JSTL for the outer iteration. There are also SubTable (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml) and TreeTable (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml) elements available. You could also adapt DataGrid or DataList elements for your purposes...